# Delay Java applet load in primefaces modal dialog

Tags: java, primefaces, applet

I have 2 xhtml pages, one normal page with some data and button for calling modal dialog. Modal dialog includes second page with java applet ( tag). I've noticed that after I click submit button browser is freezed for a few seconds while Java is loading.

```
<p:dialog header="Page2" widgetVar="dlg4" modal="true" height="350" width="550" closable="true" resizable="true" draggable="false">
  <ui:include src="itemSigning.xhtml" />
</p:dialog>
```

If I'm correct, primefaces works this way: when page 1 loads (that have some dialogs defined), every modal dialog defined in that page is loaded, right? Is there a way to tell modal dialog to load its content at the moment it is opened?

So, I when I press submit button, I would like modal dialog to be opened instantly and applet after I open dialog (and page 2 in it) so I can write some message to user like: "Wait for a moment until Java is loaded..."

I want to avoid browser window freezing for 2-3 seconds before modal dialog is opened (probably because Java is loading at that moment).

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the Primefaces 5.1 User Guide Page 177

```
Tag: Dialog
Attribute: dynamic
Default: false
Type: Boolean
Description: Enables lazy loading of the content with ajax.
```